# In Mint 17, how do I copy/paste symlinked files?

Tags: linux-mint, symlink

In Mint 17 (Cinnamon), I'm using the file manager (I guess it's called Nemo?) to view some header files after building OpenSSL in the 'include' directory. Each of the header files in this directory has a sub-icon that looks like an arrow, I guess this means it's a symlink or soft link to a real file. I just want to copy/paste all of these header files into another directory, but when I do this I instead get copies of the link itself and not the target files.

How can I copy/paste the actual physical files and not the links, from the links themselves?

### EDIT

Here is the result of `ls -l`:

```
robert@mint-os ~/third-party-source/openssl/include/openssl $ ls -l
total 1572
lrwxrwxrwx 1 robert robert 22 Jan 23 07:54 aes.h -> ../../crypto/aes/aes.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 robert robert 24 Jan 23 07:54 asn1.h -> ../../crypto/asn1/asn1.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 robert robert 28 Jan 23 07:54 asn1_mac.h -> ../../crypto/asn1/asn1_mac.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 robert robert 25 Jan 23 07:54 asn1t.h -> ../../crypto/asn1/asn1t.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 robert robert 22 Jan 23 07:54 bio.h -> ../../crypto/bio/bio.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 robert robert 26 Jan 23 07:54 blowfish.h -> ../../crypto/bf/blowfish.h
<snip>
```

Comment: Open **Terminal** in the 'include' directory and try to check if the files are links really by `ls -lL`

Comment: @Costas I've updated my question with the results of the command.

Comment: @Costas I think that command shouldn't include `-L`, otherwise how would we distinguish between links and their target regular files?

Comment: @muru I've updated my question again with just the results of `ls -l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output, the links are all to `~/third-party-source/openssl/crypto`. So either navigate there from the GUI, or with the command line `cp`, use `--dereference`:

```
-L, --dereference
      always follow symbolic links in SOURCE
```

Like so:

```
cp -L ~/third-party-source/openssl/include/openssl/* /some/where/else
```

Comment: Using `cp` worked and is what I ended up using, but the answer I'm *really* looking for is how to do this through the GUI.

Comment: @void.pointer the file browser doesn't have an option to follow links, so what you will have to do is go to the links' target directory and copy.